# How can I check Solr index using Luke

Tags: solr, lucene, luke

How can I check my solr index using Luke? I tried pointing to my index location (solr/core1/data/index). But I am getting the error

```
Unknown format version: -12
```

Comment: what version of Luke and what version of Solr are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got that error with a nightly build of lucene (4.x) and an older luke (1.0.1) - the latest currently available from its site.

Check out & build the latest luke from here:

http://code.google.com/p/luke/source/checkout

It reads latest lucene 4.x ok, 3.x versions as well.

Comment: If someone comes to this question, this github repo (https://github.com/tarzanek/luke) is usually updated with newer versions of luke as lucene upgrades.

Answer (score 1):

As Mauricio suggests, this error means that your luke version is older than your solr version. Try updating to the newest version of Luke.

Comment: I was using the latest version of Luke downloaded from the website.